# How can I delete the many-to-many relationship between two dynamic objects?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1, system.reflection

I want to delete the many-to-many relationship between two dynamic entities.

I've seen examples using dummy objects, but they were not dynamic. I will not know the object or the name of the objects' collection navigation properties until run-time. So I can't just say,

```
apple.Oranges.Remove(orange)
```

I need to do it dynamically. Something like,

```
dynamicModel.dynamicCollection(collectionName).Remove(otherDynamicModel)
```

I don't need extension methods necessarily, just something that gets the job done. How can I do this? Thanks.

(I don't know what other details might be helpful to provide since the objects are dynamic?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're best off using reflection in this case still:

```
((dynamic)dynamicModel.GetType().GetProperty(collectionName)
   .GetValue(dynamicModel, null))
       .Remove(otherDynamicModel)
```

Or if you know it will be an `IList`

```
((IList)dynamicModel.GetType().GetProperty(collectionName)
   .GetValue(dynamicModel, null))
       .Remove(otherDynamicModel)
```